# TinyMCE 4 default font size

Tags: css, tinymce, font-size, tinymce-4

When editing in WYSIWYG mode with "TinyMCE 4" tables do not hold font format, where is the editors default text size location?

I have tried this:

```
.mce-content-body {
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #336699;
}
```

This does change the font color but nothing else.

[Screen Shot](http://www.amalgamite.com/Pics/TinyMCE.jpg)

Comment: OK figured it out its at:


../Tiny-MCE/skins/lightgray/content.min.css

tinymce {font-size: 15px;}

Comment: you should write an answerto your own question and accept it

Comment: You shouldn't modify the original source files for that. Maybe this answer will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803268/tinymce-4-default-font-size